# mypy type hinting between calling function with different types

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

I have two functions, one which accepts lists or strings and returns the type that was input and another which accepts a string and calls the first function which is used in the result.

A simplified example of this is:

```
def accepts_string_or_list(inputs: str | list) -> str | list:
    if isinstance(inputs, list):
        return inputs + ['1']
    return inputs + '1'


def accepts_string(inputs: str) -> str:
    # do something to inputs string
    return accepts_string_or_list(inputs)
```

Mypy complains on the very last line that "Incompatible return value type (got "str | list[Any]", expected "str")  [return-value]mypy". I know that the `accepts_string` function will always accept a string which implies that the return value of `accepts_string_or_list` (when used in `accepts_string`) will always return a string. Mypy doesn't know this, but how do I make type hinting work correctly here?

I know I could change the output type of `accepts_string` to be `str | list` instead of `str`. This would remove the error message, but would be untrue because only strings will be returned. For this reason, I would not want to do this.

Comment: use a type var and make the function *generic* so that it knows that if a string is passed, a string is returned

Comment: The typevar approach should work, but in practice mypy seems to have difficulty statically resolving the logic within the function (at least in my experiment here https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=572babcf88f5952f4327c8adababa188) ...Alternatively https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload gives another way to specify that when passed `str` returns `str` and when passed `list` returns `list`

Comment: @Anentropic that's because you should use *constrainted* typevar not a bound one. You want `T = TypeVar("T", str, int)`, you don't want `bound = str | int`.

Comment: Overload is useful when you have a more complex situation, e.g. two parameters that are unions and you want specific return types based on specific combinations (generally, though, you want to *avoid* that situation to begin with)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga indeed that works https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=94e511befbda0a3b29de0ad5d98ff79c 

Comment: It's not clear from this example that `accepts_string_or_list` should exist at all, instead of having two clearly distinguished functions `accepts_string` and `accepts_list`.

Comment: This is an overly simplified example, but suppose `accepts_string` does some operations first before calling `accepts_string_or_list` and `accepts_string_or_list` is used in other places, then separating them out into different functions is useful

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have defined your interface like this. You could either define two different methods, `accept_list` and `accept_string`, or have a single method called `accept`.

However, considering your current implementation, you can utilize either of the following techniques:

```
from typing import TypeVar


T = TypeVar("T", str, list)


def accepts_string_or_list(inputs: T) -> T:
    if isinstance(inputs, list):
        return inputs + ['1']
    return inputs + '1'


def accepts_string(inputs: str) -> str:
    # do something to inputs string
    return accepts_string_or_list(inputs)
```

```
from typing import overload


@overload
def accepts_string_or_list(inputs: str) -> str:
    pass


@overload
def accepts_string_or_list(inputs: list) -> list:
    pass


def accepts_string_or_list(inputs: str | list) -> str | list:
    if isinstance(inputs, list):
        return inputs + ['1']
    return inputs + '1'


def accepts_string(inputs: str) -> str:
    # do something to inputs string
    return accepts_string_or_list(inputs)
```

While it may not be considered polymorphism in the strictest sense as it applies only to types and not at runtime, in the realm of static polymorphism and type-checking, the first one could be loosely referred to as `Parametric polymorphism`, and the second one is known as `Ad hoc polymorphism`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @Alireza Roshanzamir which outlined the use of TypeVar from typing was what I was looking for.
I have also decided to use singledispatch from functools to manage the overloading as the separation of the two input types was advantageous. My solution looks something like this.

```py
from functools import singledispatch
from typing import TypeVar

StringOrList = TypeVar("StringOrList", str, list[str])

@singledispatch
def accepts_string_or_list(inputs: str | list[str]) -> StringOrList:
    raise NotImplementedError


@accepts_string_or_list.register(str)
def _(inputs: str) -> str:
    # do something to inputs string
    return inputs + '1'


@accepts_string_or_list.register(list)
def _(inputs: list[str]) -> list[str]:
    return [accepts_string_or_list(name) for name in inputs]


def accepts_string(inputs: str) -> str:
    # do something to inputs string
    return accepts_string_or_list(inputs)
```